# Convert a .fbx to a .x model

Tags: directx9, fbx

I'm trying to convert a .fbx model to a .x for use in my DirectX 9 project. Does anyone know of any software to allow me to do this?

Been googling for a few days and not really found anything that has allowed me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) can import .fbx files and output .x files.

Comment: Been trying to import it to blender, but it says its not a valid file...

Comment: Blender [claims fbx](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Import/FBX) as a supported import format. I've found that import scripts for any program are particularly fragile. You may want to ensure you're saving/exporting the fbx file properly. Otherwise, post another question with the specific messages your getting.